# Does set theory allow for infinite ascending membership chains? Is every set itself a member of another set?

Tags: set-theory

I was thinking about a variant of Russell's paradox: Is it possible to specify a set of all objects that are themselves not members of any set?

Membership in this set would be clearly contradictory. However, there's another option: perhaps this set is empty. But if that's the case, then that would imply that every set is itself a member of another set. In other words: an infinite ascending membership chain.

Does set theory allow for this? Or is my definition -- a set of all objects that are themselves not members of any set -- disallowed by one of the axioms of modern set theory?

Comment: See [Zermelo ordinals](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Natural_number#Zermelo_ordinals) : "Each natural number is then equal to the set containing just the natural number preceding it."

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA Thanks! That makes sense... so my original definition would translate to: "a number that has no greater number", perhaps? It would seem that the infinite ascending membership chain is nothing more than the cardinality of the natural numbers encoded as Zermelo ordinals...

Comment: Reading up on this, it seems like my question might be best answered by the Axiom of Infinity: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Axiom_of_infinity

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Note that for every set $x$, $$x\in\{x\},$$ where the latter set is postulated to exist per the Pairing Axiom

Comment: That makes sense, thanks! I need to wait 10 minutes to accept an answer, but this seems right: you're saying that every object is a member of its own singleton set.

Comment: Wait, would this mean that the singleton set, as a distinct object, itself has a containing singleton set? Would that imply an infinite ascending chain? (e.g. A --> {A} --> {{A}} --> {{{A}}} --> ...)

Comment: @MattD: Yes, it would; the fact that they are distinct would follow from Foundation, but if you accept an anti-foundation postulate that allows $A\in A$, you would have $\{A\}=A$, and you would also get an infinite ascending chain (though each set in the chain is equal).

Comment: Got it... so ZFC set theory *does* allow upward infinite membership chains in the trivial sense of singletons, but the axiom of foundation prevents downward infinite membership chains. Is that correct?

Comment: And does this mean that my original definition (a set containing all sets that are not members of any set) would just be empty, therefore avoiding any paradox?

Comment: @MattD Yes, that's correct. Note that also via Replacement and Infinity we in fact get, for every set $a$, the existence of the *whole singleton sequence* $\{a,\{a\},\{\{a\}\},\{\{\{a\}\}\},...\}$.

Comment: @NoahSchweber Thanks... is it possible to derive the Axiom of Infinity directly from the Axiom of Pairing, if the latter implies an infinite chain of singletons via recursive application of the rule? In other words: what does the Axiom of Infinity give us that the Axiom of Pairing can't provide? (Sorry, maybe this should be a separate question...)

Comment: @MattD Nope. $V_\omega$ - the set of hereditarily finite sets - satisfies all the ZFC axioms except Infinity.

Comment: @NoahSchweber Thanks, this has been super helpful. Sorry for the endless questions, but is $V_ω$ itself an infinite set? If so, wouldn't that satisfy Infinity by positing the existence of an infinite set?

Comment: @MattD $V_\omega$ is an infinite set, but remember: it doesn't contain itself as an element! So $V_\omega$ doesn't think that there is an infinite set: from $V_\omega$'s perspective, $V_\omega$ itself is a *proper class* (namely, the class of all sets). This can be pretty confusing at first; to keep everything clear you'll want to learn the basics of *model theory*, which makes notions like "from $V_\omega$'s perspective" precise.